# Escaping characters from password passed to Python script on the terminal

Tags: python, bash

I've written a Python script that takes some parameters on the command line. One of the parameters is the password to a MySQL database.

The password is something like: `xxXxx1!xxXXX9#xxX$$`

If I connect to mysql using: `mysql -u user -p` I'm able to connect with the password. But, passing the password as a parameter to my Python application causes an exception to be thrown. Apparently the password is incorrect.

I've tried the following:

```
$ ./scraper.py user xxXxx1!xxXXX9#xxX$$ /path/to/save/files
$ ./scraper.py user 'xxXxx1!xxXXX9#xxX$$' /path/to/save/files
$ ./scraper.py user "xxXxx1!xxXXX9#xxX$$" /path/to/save/files
```

Do I have to escape any of the characters in some way?

Comment: (1) In general, the first and third version will fail.  Does your password contain single-quotes?  If not, then the correct shell command is the second one.  (2) Putting passwords on a command line is a security risk.  If the password is important to you, use a different method, such as reading it from a file with restrictive permissions.

Comment: Is it just this password which fails, or do others fail as well?  Check you are picking the correct element from `sys.argv` in python, it should be `sys.argv[2]`.

Comment: Lacking more information from the OP, I am voting to close this question as _unclear_ and needing _additional details_.